equivalent definition of convergence to boundary
Suppose that we have a sequence $(z_n) \subset \mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half-plane. I want to prove that all limit points of $(z_n)$ are in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ iff for any compact subset $K \subset \mathbb{H}$ we have that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$ we have that $z_n \in \mathbb{H} \setminus K$. I don't know how to prove it.

You want to prove a false statement. Why?

@MoisheKohan but why is false?

Think of the sequence $z_n=i n^{(-1)^n}$.

I've edited the question. Now it's true? :))

Yes. For the backward direction, the boundary of $\mathbb{H}$ in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ is $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ and any point in $\mathbb{H}$ has a compact neighborhood contained in $\mathbb{H}$, so any limit point of any sequence satisfying your requirement cannot be in $\mathbb{H}$ itself. Thus, any such limit point must be in the boundary of $\mathbb{H}$, namely $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$.
For the forward direction, assume to the contrary that there is a compact $K \subset \mathbb{H}$ s.t. infinitely many $z_n$ are in $K$. Then compactness implies there is a subsequence converging in $K$, i.e., there is a limit point of $(z_n)$ in $K \subset \mathbb{H}$.

All have sene now! THANKS YOU VERY MUCH!
